# Queuing mechanism to control table transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Is there any mechanism to queue up the actions over a table into a queue and which can be processed using a procedure?
Say I have 5 transactions that need to be performed over a table as one after another but we have to manage it in such a way that only after the first transaction completion the second one is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use app locks for this.

```
BEGIN TRAN
 EXEC sp_getapplock 'foo', 'exclusive'
```

They are fast and you can release app locks when you're done, even in the middle of a transaction. Please read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql).